# Failing to post uers data to the datebase in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I Have been trying for a few hours to get this data to post to the users correct attributes in mongodb. from the form in the admin tool i have been working on. First is the form,  second is the route of the post request, and third is the data getting console.logged

```
<form action="/snake/admin/users/<%=users._id%>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <h1><%=users.username%></h1>
        <sub>Users Id Number: <%=users._id%></sub>
        <div>
        <input type="text"  value="<%=users.username%>" hidden></input>
        <label for="isAdmin">Has Admin Rights</label>
             <!--<input type="text" name="isAdmin" value="<%=users.isAdmin%>"></input>-->
        <div class="col-md-6 center">
        </div> 

        <label for="isFavUser">Has Discount Perk</label>
        <select name="isFavUser">
            <option>Is set to <%=users.isFavUser%></option>
            <option name="isFavUser" value="true">True</option>
            <option name="isFavUser" value="false">False</option>
        </select>
        <div class="col-md-6 center">
        <button>Change Rights?</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>

router.put("/snake/admin/users/:id", function(req, res){
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.user, function(err, updatedUser){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            res.render("error");
        }else{
            res.render("admin/profile", {users: updatedUser});
            console.log(req.body);
            console.log(updatedUser);
        }
    });
});
 //=====================================================
{ isFavUser: 'true' }  //This is the info getting sent

{ isAdmin: true,
  isOwner: false,
  isFavUser: false, // this is the info that should have been changed
  _id: ************************,
 username: 'SamTheTech',
 email: '###########@gmail.com',
 __v: 0 }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.put("/snake/admin/users/:id", function(req, res){
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.user, function(err, updatedUser)
```

should have been.

```
router.put("/snake/admin/users/:id", function(req, res){
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, updatedUser)
```